# ZK -Set the combo selected item in Java

Tags: zk, zul

I am populating combo box items from ZK Java with the following code

```
combo.setModel(new ListModelArray(this.reasons));
combo.setSelectedItem(combo.getItems().get(2));
combo.setSelectedIndex(3);//tried this as well.
```

Both the cases it is throwing

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 0
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent$ChildIter.<init>(AbstractComponent.java:3267) ~[zk-8.0.2.1.jar:3.6.4]
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent$ChildIter.<init>(AbstractComponent.java:3259) ~[zk-8.0.2.1.jar:3.6.4]
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent$Children.listIterator(AbstractComponent.java:217) ~[zk-8.0.2.1.jar:3.6.4]
```

Anyinputs?

Comment: Set your Selected item in your model.

Answer (score 0):

When working with a model, set the selection to the model directly. The comboitems don't render eagerly but once they render they reflect the current ListModel's state.

Either keep a reference to your model:

```
ListModelArray<String> reasonsModel = new ListModelArray<>(this.reasons);
combo.setModel(reasonsModel);
reasonsModel.addToSelection(this.reasons[2]);
```

... or get it from the combobox:

```
ListModelArray<String> reasonsModel = new ListModelArray<>(this.reasons);
combo.setModel(reasonsModel);
...
((Selectable<String>) combo.getModel()).addToSelection(this.reasons[2]);
```

To get the current selection out of the model (might be nothing selected):

```
Optional<String> selected = reasonsModel.getSelection().stream().findAny();
```

Comment: `getSelectablemodel()` is a [private method in zk 8.5.0](https://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zul/Combobox.html). I think you have to cast `getModel()` to be able to use `addToSelection()`.